# IntStream leads to array elements being wrongly set to 0 (JVM Bug, Java 11)

Tags: java, arrays, java-stream, simd, java-11

In the class `P` below, the method `test` seems to return identically `false`:

```java
import java.util.function.IntPredicate;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class P implements IntPredicate {
    private final static int SIZE = 33;

    @Override
    public boolean test(int seed) {
        int[] state = new int[SIZE];
        state[0] = seed;
        for (int i = 1; i < SIZE; i++) {
            state[i] = state[i - 1];
        }
        return seed != state[SIZE - 1];
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long count = IntStream.range(0, 0x0010_0000).filter(new P()).count();
        System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```

Combining class `P` with `IntStream`, however, the method `test` can (wrongly) return `true`.
The code in the `main` method above results in some positive integer, like `716208`.
The result changes after every execution.

This **unexpected behavior** occurs because the `int` array `state[]` can be set to zero during the execution.
If a testing code, such as

```
if (seed == 0xf_fff0){
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(state));
}
```

is inserted at the tail of the method `test`, then the program will output a line like `[1048560, 1048560, 1048560, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`.

**Question:** Why can the int array `state[]` be set to zero?

I already know how to avoid this behavior: just replacing `int[]` with `ArrayList`.

I examined in:

- windows 10 + and debian 10+ with  OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 15.0.1+9-18) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 15.0.1+9-18, mixed mode, sharing)
- debian 9 + OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 13.0.1+9) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 13.0.1+9, mixed mode, sharing)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

One can reproduce the problem with an even simpler example, namely:

```
class Main {
    private final static int SIZE = 33;

    public static boolean test2(int seed) {
        int[] state = new int[SIZE];
        state[0] = seed;
        for (int i = 1; i < SIZE; i++) {
            state[i] = state[i - 1];
        }
        return seed != state[SIZE - 1];
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long count = IntStream.range(0, 0x0010_0000).filter(Main::test2).count();
        System.out.println(count);

    }
}
```

The problem is caused by the `JVM` optimization flag that allows the vectorization (SIMD) of loops (*i.e.*, `-XX:+AllowVectorizeOnDemand`). Likely arises from applying vectorization on the same array with intersecting ranges (*i.e.,* `state[i] = state[i - 1];`). A similar issue would be possible to reproduce if the `JVM` would (for some of the elements of the `IntStream.range(0, 0x0010_0000)`), optimize the loop:

```
   for (int i = 1; i < SIZE; i++)
       state[i] = state[i - 1];
```

into:

```
    System.arraycopy(state, 0, state, 1, SIZE - 1);
```

For instance:

```
class Main {
    private final static int SIZE = 33;

    public static boolean test2(int seed) {
        int[] state = new int[SIZE];
        state[0] = seed;
        System.arraycopy(state, 0, state, 1, SIZE - 1);
        if(seed == 100)
           System.out.println(Arrays.toString(state));
        return seed != state[SIZE - 1];
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long count = IntStream.range(0, 0x0010_0000).filter(Main::test2).count();
        System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```

output:

```
[100, 100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

**NEW UPDATE: 01/01/2021**

I have sent an email to one of the Developers involved in the *implementation/integration* of that flag `-XX:+AllowVectorizeOnDemandand` received the following reply:

> It is known that part of AllowVectorizeOnDemand code is broken.
>
> There was fix (it excluded executing broken code which does incorrect
> vectorization) which was backported into jdk 11.0.11:
>
> https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk-updates/jdk11u-dev/rev/69dbdd271e04
>
> If you can, try build and test latest OpenJDK11u from
> https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk-updates/jdk11u-dev/

From the first link, one can read the following:

> @bug 8251994
> @summary Test vectorization of Streams$RangeIntSpliterator::forEachRemaining
> @requires vm.compiler2.enabled & vm.compMode != "Xint"
>
> @run main compiler.vectorization.TestForEachRem test1
> @run main compiler.vectorization.TestForEachRem test2
> @run main compiler.vectorization.TestForEachRem test3
> @run main compiler.vectorization.TestForEachRem test4

From the comments on the JIRA [story](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8251994) on that bug, one can read:

> I found the cause of the issue. To improve a chance to vectorize a
> loop, superword tries to hoist loads to the beginning of loop by
> replacing their memory input with corresponding (same memory slice)
> loop's memory Phi :
> http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/8f73aeccb27c/src/hotspot/share/opto/superword.cpp#l471
>
> Originally loads are ordered by corresponding stores on the same
> memory slice. But when they are hoisted they loose that ordering -
> nothing enforce the order.  In test6 case the ordering is preserved
> (luckily?) after hoisting only when vector size is 32 bytes (avx2) but
> they become unordered with 16 (avx=0 or avx1) or 64 (avx512) bytes
> vectors.
> (...)
>
> I have simple fix (use original loads ordering indexes) but looking on
> the code which causing the issue I see that it is bogus/incomplete -
> it does not help cases listed for JDK-8076284 changes:
>
> https://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/hotspot-compiler-dev/2015-April/017645.html
>
> **Using unrolling and cloning information to vectorize is interesting
> idea but as I see it is not complete.** Even if pack_parallel() method
> is able created packs they are all removed by filter_packs() method.
> And additionally the above cases are vectorized without hoisting loads
> and pack_parallel - I verified it.  That code is useless now and I
> will put it under flag to not run it. It needs more work to be useful.
> I reluctant to remove the code because may be in a future we will have
> time to invest into it.

This might explain why when I was comparing the assembly of the versions with and without the flag `-XX:+AllowVectorizeOnDemand`, I notice that the version with the flag for the following code:

```
   for (int i = 1; i < SIZE; i++)
       state[i] = state[i - 1];
```

(that I extract on a method called `hotstop` to facilitate looking for it in the assembly), had:

```
00000001162bacf5: mov    %r8d,0x10(%rsi,%r10,4)
0x00000001162bacfa: mov    %r8d,0x14(%rsi,%r10,4)
0x00000001162bacff: mov    %r8d,0x18(%rsi,%r10,4)
0x00000001162bad04: mov    %r8d,0x1c(%rsi,%r10,4)
0x00000001162bad09: mov    %r8d,0x20(%rsi,%r10,4)
0x00000001162bad0e: mov    %r8d,0x24(%rsi,%r10,4)
0x00000001162bad13: mov    %r8d,0x28(%rsi,%r10,4)
0x00000001162bad18: mov    %r8d,0x2c(%rsi,%r10,4)  ;*iastore {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                                             ; - AAAAAA.Main::hotstop@15 (line 21)
```

Which looks to me like a loop `unrolling`, a side from that, the method `java.util.stream.Streams$RangeIntSpliterator::forEachRemaining` showed up only in the assembly of the version with the flag.

Comment: Thank you @dreamcrash for your answer. The disabling option `-XX:-AllowVectorizeOnDemand` worked correctly and the output was what I expected. Thank you.